# Entangled ArrayLists in Java... very strange issue

Tags: java, arraylist

So I define 2 arrayLists with arraylists inside

```
ArrayList <ArrayList> var1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList <ArrayList> var2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

Then I initialize var1:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    var1.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    var1.get(i).add(1);
}
```

Then i copy var1 into var2 and i erase var1..

```
for(int k=0;k<var1.size();k++){
        var2.add(var1.get(k));
    }
    var1.clear();
```

Then I copy var2 to var1 2 times

```
for(int k=0;k<var2.size();k++){
        var1.add(var2.get(k));
for(int k=0;k<var2.size();k++){
        var1.add(var2.get(k));
```

And now the stragest thing happen... the array `var1.get(k)` is entangled with `var1.get(k+3)`... so 0 with 3, 1 with 4 and 2 with 5 in the following way...

if I do `var1.get(0).clear()`
it doesn't only erase `var1.get(0)`... but i ALSO erases `var1.get(3)`
if I do `var1.get(0).add(1)`... it doesn't only add the integer 1 into `var1.get(0)` but it also adds it into `var1.get(3)`

Also, if I do `var2.clear()` it also clears `var1`

Please some good soul can tell me why this magic is happening?

And what is the correct way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two loops (and I'm assuming they are not nested, since otherwise this code wouldn't pass compilation) copy each inner `List` reference twice from `var2` to `var1`:

```
for(int k=0;k<var2.size();k++) {
    var1.add(var2.get(k));
}
for(int k=0;k<var2.size();k++) {
    var1.add(var2.get(k));
}
```

Hence `var1.get(0)==var1.get(3)`, `var1.get(1)==var1.get(4)` & `var1.get(2)==var1.get(5)`.

Therefore when you clear the `List` referenced by `var1.get(i)`, you also clear the `List` referenced by `var1.get(i+3)` (since it's the same `List`).

> Also, if I do var2.clear() it also clears var1

You must be mistaken here. That would only happen if you assign `var1` to `var2` or vice versa.

> And what is the correct way of doing it?

If you want `var1` to contain two copies of each element of `var2`, you must create copies of the inner `ArrayList`s:

```
for(int k=0;k<var2.size();k++) {
    var1.add(new ArrayList<>(var2.get(k)));
}
for(int k=0;k<var2.size();k++) {
    var1.add(new ArrayList<>(var2.get(k)));
}
```